# ¿Por que un array con peticiones post envía lo ultimo en el codigo antes de enviar las peticiones?

Tags: angular, post, angular5, bucle-for, angular6

El problema que tengo es que quiero ejecutar ese `if` que esta al final del `for`, pero no logro hacerlo, ese `if` se ejecuta primero que todo lo anterior.

```
console.log('imagenes');
let imageCant = imagenes.length;
console.log(imageCant);
let imagePorc = 100/imageCant;
console.log(imagePorc);
let imageCargas = [];
for(n in imagenes){
  console.log(imagenes[n].file);
  const fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('uploads[]', imagenes[n].file, imagenes[n].file.name);
  this.http.post( this.url+'disenios/imagen', fd, {
    reportProgress: true,
    observe: 'events'
  }).subscribe(
    event => {
      console.log(event.type);
    },
    error => {
      console.log("Error", error);
    }
  );
  if(parseInt(n) >= (imageCant-1)){
    console.log('-----imageCargas-----');
    console.log(imageCargas);
    console.log('-----imageCargas-----');
  }
}
```

Comment: si no me equivoco en `this.http.post( this.url+'disenios/imagen', fd, {
    reportProgress: true` indicas que es una llamada async. Por lo que realiza la llamada pero no detiene la ejecución de la función. De este modo se ejecuta el resto del código antes de obtener una respuesta del servidor. Prueba cambiar este valor por "false". Saludos

Comment: @Fran Islas agregalo como respuesta

Answer (score 2):

si no me equivoco en `this.http.post( this.url+'disenios/imagen, fd, { reportProgress: true` indicas que es una llamada async. Por lo que realiza la llamada pero no detiene la ejecución de la función. De este modo se ejecuta el resto del código antes de obtener una respuesta del servidor. Prueba cambiar este valor por "false". Saludos

Comment: Si efectivamente es por eso. Gracias hermano.